# How to add a 30 second timer to end a game round?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am currently experimenting with some code that I found on the internet about a game where you have to click on one set of items and avoid clicking on the other. I am currently trying to add a timer to the game so that it lasts of a total of 30 seconds but I am really struggling to do so as I am quite inexperienced with this programming language.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {

    var gameView:SCNView!
    var SceneGame:SCNScene!
    var NodeCamera:SCNNode!
    var targetCreationTime:TimeInterval = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        View_in()
        initScene()
        initCamera()
    }

    func View_in(){
        gameView = self.view as! SCNView
        gameView.allowsCameraControl = true
        gameView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

        gameView.delegate = self
    }

    func initScene (){
        SceneGame = SCNScene()
        gameView.scene = SceneGame

        gameView.isPlaying = true

    }

    func initCamera(){
        NodeCamera = SCNNode()
        NodeCamera.camera = SCNCamera()

        NodeCamera.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:5, z:10)

        SceneGame.rootNode.addChildNode(NodeCamera)
    }

    func createTarget(){

        let geometry:SCNGeometry = SCNPyramid( width: 1, height: 1, length: 1)

        let randomColor = arc4random_uniform(2
            ) == 0 ? UIColor.green : UIColor.red

        geometry.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = randomColor

        let geometryNode = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
        geometryNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)


        if randomColor == UIColor.red {
            geometryNode.name = "enemy"
        }else{
            geometryNode.name = "friend"
        }


        SceneGame.rootNode.addChildNode(geometryNode)


        let randomDirection:Float = arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 ? -1.0 : 1.0

        let force = SCNVector3(x: randomDirection, y: 15, z: 0)

        geometryNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(force, at: SCNVector3(x: 0.05, y: 0.05, z: 0.05), asImpulse: true)
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        if time > targetCreationTime{
            createTarget()
            targetCreationTime = time + 0.6
        }

        cleanUp()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first!

        let location = touch.location(in: gameView)

        let hitList = gameView.hitTest(location, options: nil)

        if let hitObject = hitList.first{
            let node = hitObject.node

            if node.name == "friend" {
                node.removeFromParentNode()
                self.gameView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            }else {
                node.removeFromParentNode()
                self.gameView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
    }

    func cleanUp() {
        for node in SceneGame.rootNode.childNodes {
            if node.presentation.position.y < -2 {
                node.removeFromParentNode()
            }
        }
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Timer` object, documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer). Just set up the timer when you want the game to start, probably once you've finished all your initializations. When you set up the timer, just wait for it to call back to your code when it finishes and run whatever logic you want to use to terminate your game.

Comment: Not sure why this answer wasn't accepted.  let checkWaveTime = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { _ in self.subtractValueTakeAction() }) - just make sure it runs in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT***

Create a variable representing the time you want your game will end:

```
    var time: CGFloat = 60
```

Then, add an SCNAction to your scene so that each second it will decrease this variable value, for example in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
    //One second before decrease the time
    let wait = SCNAction.wait(forDuration: 1)

    //This is the heart of this answer
   // An action that reduce the time and when it is less than 1 (it reached zero) do whatever you want

    let reduceTime = SCNAction.run{ _ in
        self.time -= 1
        if self.time < 1 {
    // Do whatever you want
    // for example show a game over scene or something else
            }
        }
    }

    SceneGame.rootNode.run(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.sequence([wait,reduceTime])))
```

If you want, you can show the remaining time by using `SKLabel` on an HUD, which is an `SKScene` used as ***overlay***.

You can [check this tutorial](https://medium.com/@rogerboesch/scenekit-from-zero-to-hero-part-iii-3144b7554d72) for how to create an HUD

As well, you can use an `SCNText`, this is the [documentation about it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntext)

Comment: Hi, I copied and pasted the SCNAction code bit into the viewDidLoad section but a lot of errors suddenly came up. Could you please help me out a bit further. Also, does the 'var time: CGFloat = 60' and the 'var timeNode = SCNNode()' belong into the GameViewController section?

Comment: Both the variable must belong to your GameViewController. For the errors, I tried the code in a playground with no problems, so tell me more about them, even in private if you wish.

Comment: Also, check my edit, you don't need the ghost node "timeNode", you can make your scene rootNode to run the action

Comment: Hi, yes I would like to speak to you privately if possible as I am still not getting anywhere. How could we get to speak in private.

Comment: Let's try to solve it here, so that everyone looking for the same solution can find it easily. Anyway, if this gets too far, the system will allow us to have private messages.
Anyway, your class should look like [this in the link](https://pastebin.com/KwdZPCce) . Does it give you some error?

Comment: I literally copied and pasted that whole file and it still gives me 30+ errors. I'm not sure what the problem is and how to solve this.

Comment: Show the errors. However, I copied your code, maybe a parenthesis is missing, let's try to understand